# Missing type map or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, automapper

**Hello**,

I'm currently building an ASP.NET backend. 
For the mapping of the entities and the model object I'm using AutoMapper(Version 4.2.1).
When I send a post request with Postman for creating a task, I always get an exception which says:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: NewTask -> Task TaskManager.Web.Api.Models.NewTask ->
>   TaskManager.Data.Entities.Task
>
> Destination path: Task
>
> Source value: TaskManager.Web.Api.Models.NewTask

I tried several things out but never came to an result which worked.

Here is my AutoMapperAdapter.cs:

> I always get the errormessage in this file

```
namespace TaskManager.Common.TypeMapping {
  public class AutoMapperAdapter : IAutoMapper {
    public T Map<T>(object objectToMap) {
      try {
        return Mapper.Map<T>(objectToMap);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the AddTaskMaintenance Processor:

```
namespace TaskManager.Web.Api.MaintenanceProcessing {
  public class AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor : IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor {
    private readonly IAutoMapper _autoMapper;
    private readonly IAddTaskQueryProcessor _queryProcessor;

    public AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor(IAddTaskQueryProcessor queryProcessor, IAutoMapper autoMapper) {
      _queryProcessor = queryProcessor;
      _autoMapper = autoMapper;
    }

    public Models.Task AddTask(NewTask newTask) {
      var taskEntity = _autoMapper.Map<Data.Entities.Task>(newTask); 

      _queryProcessor.AddTask(taskEntity);

      var task = _autoMapper.Map<Models.Task>(taskEntity);

      return task;
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping of the model objects to the entities and reverse looks like that:

```
namespace TaskManager.Web.Api.AutoMappingConfiguration {
  public class NewTaskToTaskEntityAutoMapperTypeConfigurator : IAutoMapperTypeConfigurator {
    public void Configure() {
      Mapper.Initialize(conf => {
        conf.CreateMap<NewTask, TaskManager.Data.Entities.Task>()
          .ForMember(opt => opt.Version, x => x.Ignore())
          .ForMember(opt => opt.CreatedBy, x => x.Ignore())
          .ForMember(opt => opt.TaskId, x => x.Ignore())
          .ForMember(opt => opt.CreatedDate, x => x.Ignore())
          .ForMember(opt => opt.CompletedDate, x => x.Ignore())
          .ForMember(opt => opt.Status, x => x.Ignore())
          .ForMember(opt => opt.Users, x => x.Ignore());
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And the other file:

```
namespace TaskManager.Web.Api.AutoMappingConfiguration {
  public class TaskEntitiyToTaskAutoMapperTypeConfigurator : IAutoMapperTypeConfigurator {
    public void Configure() {
      Mapper.Initialize(conf => {
        conf.CreateMap<Task, Models.Task>()
        .ForMember(opt => opt.Links, x => x.Ignore())
        .ForMember(opt => opt.Status, x => x.Ignore())
        .ForMember(opt => opt.Assignees, x => x.ResolveUsing<TaskAssigneesResolver>());
      });
    }
  }
}
```

**My questions:**

What could probably be the problem with my code?

Do I have to upgrade the version of the AutoMapper?

Comment: Does your initialization code with the mapping get called?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes, it get's called.